# RubyMine : Missing connexion on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sqlite, rubymine

When I try to connect a new project
look at the results:

```
**~/essai1$ rails server**  
/home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so (LoadError)
from /home/v/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

And:

```
**~/essai1$ rails server -e**  
/home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:316:in `parse_options'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:191:in `options'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in `set_environment'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `new'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /home/v/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/v/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

And:

```
**~/essai1$ rails server -p**  
/home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:316:in `parse_options'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:191:in `options'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in `set_environment'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `new'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /home/me/essai1/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/me/essai1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Anyone has a solution?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't installed the sqlite3 binary, which is different from the ruby gem.  On Ubuntu you can install it using "sudo apt-get install sqlite3".

Comment: thanks Dean but finally I get the same result:                                                home/me/myProject/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/me/myProject/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so (LoadError)

Comment: .. and it seems that the problem doesn't come from such "incompatible library version" because when I restart a project from scratch, I can open the localhost page of Ruby. While I couldn't do that with my previous project. It means that at one step of the building I changed datas til geting an "incompatible library version" as consequence